# How to know if browser is ready to play audio (user interaction, PWA downloaded etc)

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I got a web app with audio tag. What I want is:

Scenario 1:
Browser is not allowed, for **ANY reason (user interaction OR any other)**, to play audio. Audio player stays paused.
Scenario 2:
Browser is allowed to reproduce audio. Audio player get started by itself.

Here i put the pseudocode:

```
if (AudioPermission().getAudioallowed())  {
  player.play();
}
```

I don't want to fire any test play(), or register any user attempts to interact with the page. I just want to know if browser can play audio media at a specific moment.

Is this possible?

Comment: Doubt it. I could have my browser set the _ask_ before a page can play audio, but there is of course no way of getting the result of that before I actually _get_ asked.

Comment: Look in [Audio events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#events), there is events when browser _can_ play, but need buffering or data has failed to be fetched, etc.

Comment: See: [MDN Autoplay guide for media and Web Audio APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide) Toward the end it mentions a flag called HTMLMediaElement.allowedToPlay, but I've not seen references to it elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no way to do that right now. The fairly popular [can-autoplay](https://github.com/video-dev/can-autoplay) package is also trying to play something in order to find out if it's possible or not.

There is a proposal for a new standard called [Autoplay Policy Detection](https://w3c.github.io/autoplay) which would solve this problem but it is not implemented in any browser so far.